# Get integer data from word tables

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have several word tables that I want to edit based on the value in the last row of the column. I want to delete column contents (except last row of specified column) if the value in the last row exceeds 20.

I have used `. Range. Text`but I am having challenges with its implementation. I have this

```
For i = 3 To . Columns. Count

If   ActiveDocument.Tables(i).Cell(ActiveDocument. Tables(i).Rows.Count, i).Range.Text >20 Then ...
```

How can I get VBA to return the contents of a cell not as a string but as an integer for calculation.

Comment: Use `CInt(...)` to convert string to integer

Comment: I used this as well to convert the value from Variatus' solution to an integer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA's VAL() function will convert a string containing a numeric value into a number. The function starts from the left and recognises numbers until a non-numeric character is encountered and ignores everything that follows. In the case of text taken from a table cell that is very useful because the End-Of-Cell marker included in the text will be ignored.

```
Dim C As Long

For C = 1 To 3
    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
        If Val(.Rows.Last.Cells(C).Range.Text) > 20 Then
            Debug.Print "Delete rows above"
        End If
    End With
Next C
```